# python re.search

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

```
line=a name="12123" adfii  41:05:992 wp=wp2 this is the rate: controlled not max; time=300 loops for the system: process=16.0 sharesize=6b2k .
```

What is the best way to re.search the line for anything before and after the equal sign. example i want to be left with  name=12123 time=300 process=16.0 sharesize=6b2k. Then put in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!python3

import re

line = 'line=a name="12123" adfii  41:05:992 wp=wp2 this is the rate: controlled not max; time=300 loops for the system: process=16.0 sharesize=6b2k'

pattern = r'(\w+)=(\w+|".+?")'

lst = re.findall(pattern, line)
print(lst)

d = dict(lst)
print(d)
print(d['process'])
```

It prints the following on my screen:

```
c:\tmp\___python\njau_ndirangu\so13758903>py a.py
[('line', 'a'), ('name', '"12123"'), ('wp', 'wp2'), ('time', '300'), ('process', '16'), ('sharesize', '6b2k')]
{'line': 'a', 'sharesize': '6b2k', 'time': '300', 'name': '"12123"', 'process': '16', 'wp': 'wp2'}
16
```

Of course, you can write directly:

```
d = dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\w+|".+?")', line))
```

The `.findall` returns the list of matches where one match is represented as a tuple with subgroups as elements (the things in parentheses inside the pattern).

But be carefull with regular expressions. You can easily make an error.